# try / else with return in try block

Tags: python, exception

I came across a strange behavior in python. I could not find information about this in the python help or on SE so here it is:

```
def divide(x, y):
    print 'entering divide'
    try:
        return x/y
    except:
        print 'error'
    else:
        print 'no error'
    finally:
        print 'exit'

print divide(1, 1)
print divide(1, 0)
```

the output:

```
entering divide
exit
1
entering divide
error
exit
None
```

It seems that python will not go inside the `else` block if a value is returned in the `try`. However, it will always go in the `finally` block. I don't really understand why. Can someone help me with this logic?

thanks

Answer (score 68, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement

> The optional else clause is executed if and when control flows off the
>   end of the try clause.
>
> Currently, control “flows off the end” except in the case of an
>   exception or the execution of a return, continue, or break statement.

Comment: Pity there isn't an `else` equivalent that's guaranteed to run if an exception wasn't caught, even if the try `return`s or an uncaught exception is raised (this also stops the `else` from running)

Answer (score 27):

The reason for this behaviour is because of the `return` inside `try`.

When an exception occurs, both `finally` and `except` blocks execute before `return`. Otherwise only `finally` executes and `else` doesn't because the function has already returned.

This works as expected:

```
def divide(x, y):
    print 'entering divide'
    result = 0
    try:
        result = x/y
    except:
        print 'error'
    else:
        print 'no error'
    finally:
        print 'exit'

    return result

print divide(1, 1)
print divide(1, 0)
```

Answer (score 22):

The `else` block isn't executed because you have left the function before it got a chance to do so.

However, the `finally` block is always executed (unless you yank the power cord or something like that).

Consider this (as a thought experiment; please don't do that in real code):

```
def whoops():
    try:
        return True
    finally:
        return False
```

See what it returns:

```
>>> whoops()
False
```

If you find this confusing, you're not alone. Some languages like C# actively prevent you from placing a `return` statement in a `finally` clause.

Comment: +1 for the comment on C#. I was confused about the difference of logic between the else and the finally. It looks like a difficult design issue.

Comment: +1 for highlighting that return value can be set, let's say, twice! This is sure a bad idea in real code. Anyway, limiting the number of `return` and `raise` is always a good idea, as clarifying the code outputs.

Comment: Actually, ```try```'s return also works. What happens is the ```try```'s return statement runs 'AFTER' finally runs. Here @tim has used ```return``` 2 times first in ```try``` and other in ```finally```. Since the ```try```'s return executes after finally block, the finally is already having its own return! So the ```finally```'s return is run and 'original' ```try```'s return never got a change to run  ! Hah, finally is so powerful !

Answer (score 8):

**Why doesn't the `else` clause run?**

> A `else` clause is useful for code that must be executed **if the try clause does not raise an exception**.

- When you call `divide(1, 0)`, your `try` clause **does raise an exception** `ZeroDivisionError`, so the `else` clause does not run.
- When you call `divide(1, 1)`, the `try` clause runs successfully, **and returns**. So the `else` clause is never reached.

---

**Why does the `finally` clause always run?**

> A `finally` clause is **always executed before leaving the try statement**, whether an exception has occurred or not.

See above.

---

Reference https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/errors.html

Answer (score 1):

"return" ends the function and returns whatever you want it to return.  So it won't go on of course.  "finally" is always executed.